# How to share internet from one network card to another ethernet port

Tags: software-recommendation, networking, ethernet, fedora

I basically seek a way to "bridge" the internet connection coming into my linux machine through one ethernet port (on the mother board's NIC) and share it with another computer connected to a separate ethernet port (on a NIC using PCI). In doing this, I hope to enable both computers to have internet access, using just one available internet connection. Any ideas?

The common answer of "stop being cheap, just buy a router" won't work since it's for 2 school computer for which that isn't an option. Neither computer has Wi-Fi either.

Comment: ------bump-------

Comment: I'm afraid that that doesn't bump the question - but you can attract some more attention for your question by offering a bounty 48 hours after your question was asked.

Comment: 52 more minutes until then :D

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you want to turn your machine into a router, you probably don't really want to bridge your ethernet connections. Setting up a NATing router is simpler and more common, so there's more documentation on how to do it.

This link hits the high points of how to do that:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing

Comment: i'll try that, thx :)

Answer (score 0):

Ull need crossover cable and to share connection by in network settings wired Add new and in there IPv4 choose Method Share to other computers AND in other comp auto DHCP default setting should auto connect.

Ive done that myself and since u ask this question that means u also dont have wired router or bridge. And thats good couse they will need one more power place to use. BUt this needs 1st comp to be on all the time.

So problem remains in getting crossover cable. Either finding where is possible buying or making or ordering some it cable guy to make one or if u have tools try urself http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable

Or i can give u one witch i have :)

BUT u might not need crossover if ur ehternet card has Auto-MDIX capability.

So just 1st try with usual cable both cards if any auto crossovers signal to reciever comp and makes it work otherwise find all card specs using theyr names from terminal command `lspci` in google and change them in computers. If no succes- crossover cable rocks.

Comment: I already made my own crosser cable :D

Comment: then all is working with setting 1 shared connection.